# How to "wrap" object to automatically call superclass method instead of overriden ones?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider:

```
class A(object):
    def f(self): print("A")

class B(A):
    def f(self): print("B")

b = B()
```

I can call `A.f` on `b` by doing:

```
A.f(b)
```

Is there an easy way to "wrap" `b` such that `wrap(b).f()` calls `A.f` for any `f`?

Comment: There's nothing simple, since any solution would require mucking around with the method-resolution order (MRO) of `B`, similar to what `super` does. I would rethink your class design if you find this necessary.

Comment: @chepner I am also interested in not-so-simple solution. I have a version that "seems" to work by setting the attributes of `b` based on the one of `A` but I am not very confident in it. This is not strictly required for my design, I am just curious. I have probably used object-slicing once purposely in my life in C++ so I can live without it in python.

Comment: In C++, object slicing seems to depend the distinction between static type and dynamic type of a pointer. (Your link uses the example of `A a = b` to discard the `B`-specific information about `b`.) Python has no such distinction, as it is not a statically-typed language.

Comment: @chepner Maybe my question is slightly too broad. I don't really care about dropping everything related to `B` in `b` as it is done in C++ (e.g., if `b` has extra members). I am just interested in modifying the "method-resolution order" so that the `A` versions are used instead of the `B` ones.

Comment: @chepner I have reworded the question to remove any reference to object slicing as it seems confusing.

Comment: Add an extra parameter to the function to decide whether to call `super` method or overridden one. This is the easiest way I can think of.

Comment: @Raj You would be better off simply defining two separate methods in that case.

Comment: @chepner If you are good with defining separate methods then why bother about virtual functions, dynamic binding, etc. in any programming language.

Comment: I mean, separate methods rather than a single method whose behavior is determined by the value of a Boolean argument.

Comment: I'm not convinced that object slicing was meant as an explicit feature, but rather the consequence of defining what `A a = b` means in a statically typed language. In Python, only values, not names, have types, so there's nothing that requires object slicing as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which copies the methods from the most upper base class:

```
import types, copy

def get_all_method_names(clazz):
  return [func for func in dir(clazz) if callable(getattr(clazz, func))]

def wrap(obj):
  obj = copy.copy(obj)
  obj_clazz = obj.__class__
  base_clazz = obj_clazz.__bases__[-1] # the one which directly inherits from object
  base_methods = get_all_method_names(base_clazz) # list of all method names in base_clazz
  for base_method_name in base_methods:
    base_method = getattr(base_clazz, base_method_name) # get the method object
    if isinstance(base_method, types.FunctionType): # skip dunder methods like __class__, __init__
      setattr(obj, base_method_name, base_method) # copy it into our object
  return obj

# class declaration from question here

wrapped_b = wrap(b)

wrapped_b.f(wrapped_b) # prints A, unfortunately we have to pass the self parameter explicitly
b.f() # prints B, proof that the original object is untouched
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels dirty to me, but it also seems to work.  I'm not sure I'd rely on this for anything important.

```
import copy

def upcast(obj, clazz):
    if not isinstance(obj, clazz):  # make sure we're actually "upcasting"
        raise TypeError()
    wrapped = copy.copy(obj)
    wrapped.__class__ = clazz
    return wrapped
```

This results in

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.f()
A
>>> b = B()
>>> b.f()
B
>>> upcast(b, A).f()
A
```

What I've really done here is essentially monkey-patch a clone of `b` and lied to it and told it it's actually an `A`, so when it comes time to resolve which version of `f` to call, it'll call the one from `A`.

Answer (score -1):

Object Slicing is not supported in python the way it is done in C++ (The link you are pointing to takes a cpp example).
In Python Object Slicing is a rather different thing which means to slice up any object which supports sequence protocol (implements **getitem**() and **len**() methods).
Example :

```
    A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    print(A[1:3])
```

But in C++ Object Slicing is just cutting off the properties added by a base class instance when assigned to a parent class variable.

Comment: I know what slicing is in Python. I am asking how to do something similar to what object slicing is in C++ in python, not what slicing is in python.

Comment: @Holt it is not supported in python